# lwjgl 3: No GLCapabilities instance set for the current thread. glCreateProgram()

Tags: java, shader, lwjgl

I can not solve the problem in question. I tried several solutions to this error but without any positive result. If i try to remove glCreateProgram() method the error move to glCreateShader() method.

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No GLCapabilities instance set for the current thread. Possible solutions:
    a) Call GL.createCapabilities() after making a context current in the current thread.
    b) Call GL.setCapabilities() if a GLCapabilities instance already exists for the current context.
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL.getCapabilities(GL.java:238)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glCreateProgram(GL20.java:209)
    at ms.shaders.ShaderProgram.<init>(ShaderProgram.java:18)
    at ms.shaders.Shaders.<init>(Shaders.java:8)
    at ms.renderer.Renderer.<init>(Renderer.java:13)
    at ms.main.MainGame.<clinit>(MainGame.java:16)
```

**ShaderProgram**

```
package ms.shaders;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public abstract class ShaderProgram {

    private int programID;
    private int vShaderID;
    private int fShaderID;

    public ShaderProgram(String vShader, String fShader)  {

        programID = glCreateProgram(); //Error line

        String vertexShaderSource = loadShader(vShader);

        vShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vShaderID, vertexShaderSource);

        glCompileShader(vShaderID);

        if (glGetShaderi(vShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error creating vertex shader\n"
                    + glGetShaderInfoLog(vShaderID, glGetShaderi(vShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH)));
        }

        glAttachShader(programID, vShaderID);

        String fragmentShaderSource = loadShader(vShader);

        fShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fShaderID, fragmentShaderSource);

        glCompileShader(fShaderID);

        if (glGetShaderi(fShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error creating vertex shader\n"
                    + glGetShaderInfoLog(fShaderID, glGetShaderi(fShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH)));
        }

        glAttachShader(programID, vShaderID);
    }

    protected abstract void bindAttribute();

    protected void bindAttribute(int attribute, String name) {
        glBindAttribLocation(programID, attribute, name);
    }

    public void link() {

        glLinkProgram(programID);

        if(glGetProgrami(programID, GL_LINK_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to link program: ");
        }
    }

    public void validate() {

        glValidateProgram(programID);

        if(glGetShaderi(programID, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to validate program: ");
        }
    }

    public void bind() {
        glUseProgram(programID);
    }

    public void unbind() {
        glUseProgram(0);
    }

    public void dispose() {

        unbind();

        glDetachShader(programID, vShaderID);
        glDetachShader(programID, fShaderID);
        glDeleteShader(vShaderID);
        glDeleteShader(fShaderID);
        glDeleteProgram(programID);
    }

    private static String loadShader(String file) {

        StringBuilder shaderSource = new StringBuilder();

        try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            String line;

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                shaderSource.append(line).append("//\n");
            }

            reader.close();

        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        return shaderSource.toString();
    }
}
```

**Renderer**

```
package ms.renderer;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.*;

import ms.renderer.VertexArrayObject.Vertex;
import ms.shaders.Shaders;

public class Renderer {

    VertexArrayObject vertex = new VertexArrayObject();
    Shaders shaders = new Shaders();

    public void prepare() {

        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    public void render(Vertex vertex) {

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        shaders.bind();

        glBindVertexArray(vertex.getVaoID());
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, vertex.getVertexCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        shaders.unbind();
    }

    public void clear() {

        shaders.dispose();
        vertex.cleanUp();
    }
}
```

**MainGame**

```
package ms.main;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;

import ms.input.KeyboardInput;
import ms.renderer.Renderer;
import ms.renderer.VertexArrayObject;
import ms.renderer.VertexArrayObject.Vertex;
import ms.utils.FinalVariables;

public class MainGame implements Runnable {

    private Thread thread;

    private static Display display = new Display();
    private static Renderer renderer = new Renderer();
    private static VertexArrayObject loader = new VertexArrayObject();

    private static int WIDTH = FinalVariables.WIDTH;
    private static int HEIGHT = FinalVariables.HEIGHT;
    private static String TITLE = FinalVariables.TITLE;

    private boolean isRunning = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MainGame game = new MainGame();

        display = new Display(WIDTH, HEIGHT, TITLE);
        game.start();
    }

    public void start() {

        isRunning = true;

        thread = new Thread(this, "MainThread");
        thread.start();
    }

    public void run() {

        display.init();
        display.libVersion();

        float[] positions = new float[]{

                -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                 0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
        };

        int[] indices = new int[]{

                0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2

        };

        Vertex vertex = loader.loadToVAO(positions, indices);

        while(isRunning) {

            update();
            renderer.prepare();
            renderer.render(vertex);

            if(glfwWindowShouldClose(display.window)) {
                isRunning = false;
            }
        }

        renderer.clear();
    }

    public void update() {

        if(KeyboardInput.isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE)) {
            isRunning = false;
        }

        glfwSwapBuffers(display.window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}
```

**Display** Where i call createCapabilities method

```
package ms.main;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;

import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWKeyCallback;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWVidMode;

import ms.input.KeyboardInput;

public class Display {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private GLFWKeyCallback keyCallback;

    private int width;
    private int height;

    private String title;

    public long window;

    public Display() {

    }

    public Display(int width, int height, String title) {

        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void init() {

        glfwInit();

        if(!glfwInit()) {
            System.err.println("Failed to initialize GLFW");
        }

        glfwDefaultWindowHints();
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GL_TRUE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

        window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, NULL, NULL);

        if(window == NULL) {
            System.err.println("Failed to create Window");
        }

        keyCallback = glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback = new KeyboardInput());

        GLFWVidMode vidMode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());

        glfwSetWindowPos(window, 
                        (vidMode.width() - width) / 2, 
                        (vidMode.height() - height) / 2);

        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        glfwSwapInterval(1);
        glfwShowWindow(window);

        createCapabilities();
    }

    public void libVersion() {

        System.out.println("LWJGL Version: " + glfwGetVersionString());
        System.out.println("OpenGL Version: " + glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

The problem I think is in the createCapabilities() method position but I do not know how to solve.
State that I am a beginner and I'm getting closer now to the creation of video games.

Thanks in advance for any solutions.

Comment: Have you read the error? It IS trying to help you: No GLCapabilities instance set for the current thread. Possible solutions:
    a) Call GL.createCapabilities() after making a context current in the current thread.
    b) Call GL.setCapabilities() if a GLCapabilities instance already exists for the current context.

Comment: Yes, i've read the error but i'm blind for solution. I call createCapabilities() after make context current (i think). It probably was not very clear this point. Could you tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: I am not a games programmer or a Java programmer but this is an Object instance error. You have not created an instance of the class GLCapabilities in your current thread. So you need to find out what that class is, how to create an instance of it and create one if its not already created. If it IS created, then you need to get a reference to it and call 'setCapabilities' on it before you call createCapabilities.

Comment: Can you show me how can i solve this problem? I try to solve by follow your suggestion but nothing work.

Comment: I am not a games programmer or a Java programmer so I cannot help more than I already have - you need to create a GLCapabilities.